# Replacing values in a column according to a map

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have two columns A and B in an Excel sheet, similar to the following:-

```
A   B
1   1
2   2
3   4
4   5
5   6
6   7
7   8
8   10
9   11
10  12
11  13
12  15
13  16
14  17
15  18
```

Now, in a different sheet, I have a column of B values, and I want to 'map' them to their corresponding A values. By 'map' them, I mean replace a B value with the A value that is adjacent to it in the first sheet. How do I do this?

Comment: this is a lookup or index/match process

Comment: if you need the replacement of the B values to be done in the same cell they are being indicated in, in the other sheet, then you will need to go the VBA route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1)

In sheet2 column C  you want your results and lets say and your B data is in column D just to mix things up.

```
=INDEX(SHEET1!$A$1:$A$15,MATCH(D2,SHEET1!$B$1:$B$15,0))
```

Option 2)

Same setup but lets use the LOOKUP function

```
=LOOKUP(D2,SHEET1!$B$1:$B$15,SHEET1!$A$1:$A$15)
```

Answer (score 1):

With *Sheet1* like:

[image]

and *Sheet2* like:

[image]

Running this short macro:

```
Sub Translate()
    Dim B As Range, RangeToFix As Range, r As Range
    Dim fnd As Range

    Set B = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B15")
    Set RangeToFix = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1:B11")

    For Each r In RangeToFix
        Set fnd = B.Find(What:=r.Value, After:=B(1))
        If fnd Is Nothing Then
            r.Offset(0, 1).Value = "not found"
        Else
            r.Value = fnd.Offset(0, -1).Value
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

will Produce this in *Sheet2*:

[image]

This does the "translation" in-place.